# PHP - Need a function to compare strings in an array and return only the matching part

Tags: php

I need a PHP function where I can match strings in an array and return only the matching part.

**Description**

*38001, 38002, 38003* should return 3800

*38001, 38002, 38010* should return 380

*f38001, f38002, f38100* should return f38

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

This routine is tested with these three `$numbers` arrays.

```
$numbers = array(38021, 38002, 38003);
$numbers = array(38021, 38221, 38003);
$numbers = array(380010, 38001, 38010);
$numbers = array('f38001','f38102','f38100');
```

Will work with any number of strings in the array.
Will work with strings up to 999 characters
Strings do not all have to be the same length

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;; charset=utf-8');
//$numbers = array(38001, 38002, 38003);
//$numbers = array(38001, 38002, 38010);
$numbers = array('f38001','f38102','f38100');



$len = 999;
$match = array();
$match = str_split($numbers[0]);
foreach($numbers as $key=>$value){
  $chars = str_split($value);
  $result = array();
  foreach($chars as $ndx=>$char){
    $result[$ndx] = $char;
    if($char != $match[$ndx]){
      if($len > $ndx){$len=$ndx;}
      $result = array_slice($result, 0, $len);
      break;
    }
  }
}
$answer = join($result);



echo "\na=$answer";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to it

```
<?php

$num=array();
$num=str_split(38002);
$num=str_split("f38001");
$temp=array();
echo match($num, 3)."<br>";
echo match($num, 2)."<br>";
echo match($num, 2)."<br>";
function match ($num,$match){
foreach ($num as $key => $value) {
      echo $value."";
      if (($key==$match)and ($value !== 0)){
            break;
      }
}
}
?>
```